# why my os.listdir return the same folder?

Tags: python

sory, if my english bad...
i'm trying to get a list of my dir this way:

```
import os, os.path  

_path = "/opt/local"#this because i use mac
_dir_path = os.listdir(_path)
_tmp_attr = {"name":"","type":""}
_tmp_data =[]

for _dir_name in _dir_path:
   _tmp_attr["name"] = _dir_name
   if os.path.isdir(_path+'/'+_dir_name):
     _tmp_attr["type"] = "Dictionary"
   _tmp_data.append(_tmp_attr)
print _tmp_data
```

but it print only the last directory
    [{'type': 'Dictionary', 'name': 'www'}, {'type': 'Dictionary', 'name': 'www'}, ... ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're re-using the same "_tmp_attr" dictionary in every loop iteration, so you're just re-adding the same instance to the _tmp_data collection and overwriting its contents in every iteration.

You need to initialize a new dictionary in every iteration:

```
_tmp_attr = { }
```

Comment: but i think the line 5: _tmp_attr = {"name":"","type":""} be useless

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is an object referencing issue. The _tmp_attr you are adding to the list are infact the same object. Each iteration of the loop simply updates it. You need to create a new _tmp_attr object for each iteration in-order for the list elements to be unique. When the loop falls through you are simply left with multiple references in the list to the same object.
doing this in the loop may help:

```
type = ""
if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(_path,_dir_name)):
    type = "Dictionary"
_tmp_data.append({"type":type,"name":_dir_name})
```

Answer (score 1):

you may also want to look at [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: `os.path.walk` is deprecated.